# How to use Swiss ephemeris in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Respected experts,

I know vb.net but not expert. I want to write a simple astrology program using Swiss ephemeris in VB.net. There is no example coding in VB.net but only in vb5 in internet and I can't convert that vb5 project to VB.net . If you please give me the codes to connect the swedll32.dll and to get the sun degree from it as an example in VB.net then I will be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: I found this .NET library on source forge. It might be useful https://sourceforge.net/p/swenglal/code/ci/master/tree/

Comment: Otherwise I would say that your question lacks detail. I would guess that .NET programmers who have used your specific library (wedll32.dll) aren't that many and the chance that one of the programmers who *have* used it would actually read this question is not that big. So, if you would like an answer you need to tell us more about what you have tried, where to find your dll and a link showing the vb5 example. It might be possible to port the vb5 code to vb.net. A good question is not something you need to spend tens of minutes googling to understand.